# Loop through data frame and assign a value to a value in a new column

Tags: r

I am trying to group data based on `uniqueLocation` using R.

it starts at 101 and goes to 701.

I want 101 to be 1 and 701 to be 4

This would go up to a max of 16, once it hits 16 in the count it would reset back to 1 and continue to 16 until the data set has been assigned a value between 1 & 16

Comment: Welcome to SO! Can you please share a reproducible example of your data? You can use the `dput` function on a subset of your dataset. Preferably with the counter-reseting cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `match` and `unique` to get a unique ID number for each entry. You can then use `%% 16` to reset it after every 16 value.

```
df$ID <- match(df$UniqueLocation, unique(df$UniqueLocation)) %% 16
df$ID[df$ID == 0] <- 16
```

To assign a unique string for each 16 values we can use :

```
df$ID1 <- paste0('Test_', ceiling(match(df$UniqueLocation, 
                                  unique(df$UniqueLocation))/16))
```

Comment: this worked, thanks dude. So if I was to allocate each group of a 16 its own unique string e.g. for the first set of 16 = Test_1, second set of 16 Test_2 how would I do that?